# Реализация ветвлений в Си через тернарный оператор (:?)

Tags: c

К примеру, есть код на C:

```
if (a > 0)
{
if (b > 0)
c = a;
}
else c = b;
```

Возможно ли такое записать с помощью тернарного оператора?

В данном случае, пробовала идти от ветки false в основном if, но получается, что для тернарного не хватает условия после ":". Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = a > 0 && b > 0 ? a : b;
```

Comment: При a > 0 & b < 0 делает c = b, что неправильно. Ответ

     c = a > 0 ? b > 0 ? a : c : b;

Comment: да, строго говоря, либо @alexlz прав, либо ТС неправ: в условии нужен еще один `else c = b`, чтобы ответ был верным

Answer (score 0):

```
c = (a > 0) ? (b > 0) ? a : c : b ;
```

Дословно.